# Custom circle with multiple buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am a budding android developer. I was wondering how can I draw a hollow circle with a thick boundary ring and have options embedded in the thick boundary. The number of options depend on how many user chooses (1-10). However, I do not know how to track the information on screen such as coordinates for the options in the boundary **specifically**.

Also could you please tell me how can I fix these custom queries by myself in the future as documentation is only for basic reference.

Thank you

**Circle example** (Number of options are not static but variable) [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a MappedImage with coordinates, create your [mappedimage](http://www.image-maps.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw circle using canvas

```
public class DountChart extends View {

    private int ScrWidth, ScrHeight;

    //The percentage of presentation, in actual use, is the external scale parameter
    private final float arrPer[] = new float[]{10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f};
    //RGB array of colors
    private final int arrColorRgb[][] = {{77, 83, 97},
            {148, 159, 181},
            {77, 83, 97},
            {148, 159, 181}, {77, 83, 97},
            {148, 159, 181}, {77, 83, 97},
            {148, 159, 181}, {77, 83, 97},
            {148, 159, 181}};

    public PanelDountChart2(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        //The screen information
        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        ScrHeight = dm.heightPixels;
        ScrWidth = dm.widthPixels;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Canvas background
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        float cirX = ScrWidth / 2;
        float cirY = ScrHeight / 3;
        float radius = ScrHeight / 5;//150;

        float arcLeft = cirX - radius;
        float arcTop = cirY - radius;
        float arcRight = cirX + radius;
        float arcBottom = cirY + radius;
        RectF arcRF0 = new RectF(arcLeft, arcTop, arcRight, arcBottom);

        //Brush the initialization
        Paint PaintArc = new Paint();
        Paint PaintLabel = new Paint();
        PaintLabel.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        PaintLabel.setTextSize(16);

        //Position calculation
        XChartCalc xcalc = new XChartCalc();

        float Percentage = 0.0f;
        float CurrPer = 0.0f;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arrPer.length; i++) {
            //The percentage of conversion as a pie chart display angle
            Percentage = 360 * (arrPer[i] / 100);
            Percentage = (float) (Math.round(Percentage * 100)) / 100;
            //The distribution of color
            PaintArc.setARGB(255, arrColorRgb[i][0], arrColorRgb[i][1], arrColorRgb[i][2]);

            //Display the proportion in a pie chart
            canvas.drawArc(arcRF0, CurrPer, Percentage, true, PaintArc);
            //Calculating the percentage of label
            xcalc.CalcArcEndPointXY(cirX, cirY, radius - radius / 2 / 2, CurrPer + Percentage / 2);
            //Identification
            canvas.drawText(Float.toString(arrPer[i]) + "%", xcalc.getPosX(), xcalc.getPosY(), PaintLabel);
            //The starting point of the next
            CurrPer += Percentage;
        }

        //Painting circle
        PaintArc.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawCircle(cirX, cirY, radius / 2, PaintArc);

    }

}
```